# "Refreshing" a string variable so that this multiple choice while loop doesn't repeat infinitely

Tags: c++, variables, while-loop, infinite-loop

So I'm new to C++, I'm in an intro course and tomorrows assignment is to write a program that has 5 questions, some multiple choice, some true or false.

Right now I'm working on the first multiple choice question, it has to have 4 possible answers (a, b, c, d) with conditions:

1. If the user enters the correct letter choice, it continues to the next question.
2. If the user enters an incorrect letter choice, it tells the user that they are wrong and asks them the question again.
3. If the user enters anything else besides the 4 letters, it displays an invalid input error and again, asks them the question again.

2 and 3 will happen until they enter the correct answer.

I'm trying to use a while loop (I think this is the way to go?) and then a nested if/else statement inside.

The issue I'm running into is the fact that the Q1 string variable is instantiated in the beginning when entered, and then after that can't change. Making the loop either go through (if answered correctly) or repeat infinitely.

How can I either refresh the variable so that it doesn't repeat, or maybe do this an entirely different and better way? Like I said I'm new so if I'm doing something stupid or wrong please forgive me!

Here is my current code with only one question so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string Q1;
    cout << "How many ounces are in 1 cup?" << endl;
    cout << "A. 12 \nB. 8 \nC. 16 \nD. 4" << endl;
    cin >> Q1;

    while (Q1 != "B") {
        if (Q1 == "A" || Q1 == "C" || Q1 == "D"){
            cout << "Your selected answer " << Q1 << " is incorrect, please select another answer" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Your answer is invalid, please enter either A, B, C, or D." << endl;
        }

    }
    cout << "Correct! There are 8 ounces in one cup" << endl;
}
```

Comment: um `cin >> Q1;` at the end of the loop?

Comment: @NathanOliver Wow I feel really stupid, it really was that simple. For some reason I was imagining when being re-asked the question it would also have to re-ask the possible answers but that is really pointless. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have an infinite loop. You never ask for user input again. You need to add `cin >> Q1` to the end of the loop:

```
while (Q1 != "B") {
     if (Q1 == "A" || Q1 == "C" || Q1 == "D"){
         cout << "Your selected answer " << Q1 << " is incorrect...
     }
     else {
         cout << "Your answer is invalid, please enter either...
     }
     cin >> Q1;
}
```

[Here is a live example.](http://ideone.com/8ThlRr)

Answer (score 0):

```
while (cin>>Q1) 
{
                if(Q1 == "B")
                {
                    cout << "Next question\n";
                    break;
                }
                if (Q1 == "A" || Q1 == "C" || Q1 == "D"){
                    cout << "Your selected answer " << Q1 << " is incorrect, please select another answer" << endl;
                }
                else {
                    cout << "Your answer is invalid, please enter either A, B, C, or D." << endl;
                }
  }
```

This isnt the 100% right answer but should guide you in the right direction. I have used a `break;`to exit the loop but you do not have to.

Cheers